# MathJax buttons/hotkeys script

Tags: discussion, mathjax

I've written a script that lets you insert dollar symbols automatically(via a keyboard shortcut or button) in the editor window on Stack Exchange sites that support MathJax. You guys also get a special `NP` button(<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd>, S for sansserif) that encloses the selection in `$\mathsf{...}$`.

Also, note that <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> lets you exit math mode--this lets you type math smoothly. For example, you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd>, type PSPACE, and  then use <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> to bring the cursor out of math mode, where you can continue typing. (It's been a big help to me on chem.SE, with the `\ce{...}` button--I can type chemical formulae within the flow of the code).

Also, you have <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd> for Big O notation, but I doubt you'll use it.

Feel free to check it out!

[Installation instructions and details here](https://stackapps.com/questions/3373/mathjax-buttons)

Comment: Nice idea. It can imo be improved by entering mathmode with ALT-Z, too, and then providing several shortcuts for common stuff until the next ALT-Z.

Comment: @Raphael interesting idea.. I'd have to teach it to differentiate between inside and outside math mode. Common stuff as in? Examples?

Comment: Note that Alt-Z enters math mode as well already.

Comment: Cool, that was not clear from your explanation. Certainly `mathsf`, `mathrm` and `operatorname`. Maybe `frac`. Environments like `cases` and `align` (maybe with two lines prefilled?) might be good, too. The possibilities are endless! I imagine it should be easy to build it such that users can easily edit their own combinations in?

Comment: @Raphael: I _am_ thinking of adding customizability, but that's not in the _too_ near future. I imagine that `localStorage` would make it easy.

Note that this isn't supposed to be a catch-all LaTeX editor. This is just for the common ones. Too many and the editor bar explodes (I _can_ add stuff as only-keyboard-shortcuts, though--you guys already have a big O hidden shortcut [Alt-O]). 


I think what I'll do is leave it as-is for now, and pre-program some extra buttons which you can custom-add (as well as an option to create your own). That'll take a while, though.

Comment: Oh, I was thinking only about shortcuts. Buttons are way too slow, anyway, and only useful if you don't know LaTeX. I imagine the what macros you use most depends heavily on where you write most your answers, topic-wise, so it is probably hard to make general recommendations.

Comment: @Raphael: Alright. I'll be sure to let you know when I add customizability --though since the script auto-updates, you may find out yourself :)